# Consume RESTful data with React and Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

how can I retrieve the data from https://api.github.com/search/users?q=jason and render it in React? I tried something like:

```
constructor(){
  this.state = {
    data: []            
  };
}

componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("https://api.github.com/search/users?q="+_searchTerm)
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        data: _.values(res.data.items)
                    })
                }); 
}


render() {
  const listProducts = this.state.data.map((product) => 
    <li key={product.toString()}>{product}</li>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{listProducts}</ul>     
    </div>
   );
}
```

but it didn't work. I get the error message:

Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): 
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {login, id, avatar_url, gravatar_id, ...). 
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

so I guess is that I have to convert the response to an array. But I am not too sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an object rather than a component or a string.

Change this;

```
const listProducts = this.state.data.map((product) => 
    <li key={product.toString()}>{product}</li>
);
```

to this

```
// you need to set key to a unique string like id
const listProducts = this.state.data.map((product) => 
    <li key={product.id}>{JSON.stringify(product)}</li>
);
```